# Cannot load backup data from GCS to BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

My backup table has 3 files: 2 ending with .backup_info and one folder with another folder containing 10 CSV files. What would be format of the URL which will specify the backup file location?

I'm trying below and every time I get a file not found error.

`gs://bucket_name/name_of_the_file_which_ended_with_backup_info.info`

Comment: Can you please provide some more information e.g. are you using the web UI or the API? Can you share your code? There's really not enough information here for somebody to help you. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

When you go to look at your file from your backup, it should have a structure like this:

```
Buckets/app-id-999999999-backups
```

And the filenames should look like:

```
2017-08-20T02:05:19Z_app-id-999999999_data.json.gz
```

Therefore the path will be:

```
gs://app-id-9999999999-backups/2017-08-20T02:05:19Z_app-id-9999999999_data.json.gz
```

Make sure you do not include the word "Buckets", I am guess that is the confusion.